# Conic curve having 5 points concurrent normals at the origin.

Tags: proof-verification, analytic-geometry

> Consider the curve represented by the equation $ax^2+2bxy+cy^2+d=0$ in the plane where $a>0 ,c>0$ and $ac>b^2$.Suppose that the normals to the curve drawn at $5$-distinct points on the curve all pass through the origin.Then,
>
> $(a)$ $a=c$ and $b>0$.
>
> $(b)$ $a \ne c$ and $b=0$.
>
> $(c)$ $a \ne c$ and $b<0$.
>
> $(d)$ None of the above.

**My attempt** $:$

Let $(x_{1}, y_{1})$ be one of the points on the given curve at which the normal to the given curve passes through the origin.Now the equation of the normal at the point $(x_{1} , y_{1})$ is :

$(y-y_1)(ax_1 +by_1) =(bx_1 + cy_1)(x-x_1)$.

As it passes through the origin so we have $b({x_{1}}^2 - {y_{1}}^2)-(a-c)x_1 y_1 = 0$.

This shows that the points on the given curve at which normals drawn pass through the origin will lie on the curve $b({x}^2 - {y}^2)-(a-c)x y = 0$.

So the given curve and the curve just obtained has five common points.Since the curves are quadratic in $x$ and $y$ having five common points.So these two curves should coincide (because $5$ constraints will determine $4$-unknowns uniquely).Now equating the coefficients of like terms of these two equations we have :

$ab+bc=0 , 2b^2 = a(c-a)$ and $bd=0$.Since $a>0,c>0$ we must have $a+c>0$ and hence $b=0$.Hence from the second equation we have $c=a$ since $a>0$.

So the correct option should be $a=c$ and $b=0$.Hence $(a),(b)$ and $(c)$ are all incorrect.Hence $(d)$ is the only correct option.

Is the above reasoning correct at all?Please verify it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct, but I did not check your computation

Comment: Hint: the curve is a circle.

Comment: This is exactly what I have proved.Thanks.

Comment: If we put $x=0$ and $y=0$ in the equation of the normal passing through $(x_{1} , y_{1})$ then what do we get?How can we get $\pm$?Would you please explain me?

Comment: Duplicate of the recent question (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2279993)

Comment: But @Jean Marie the link you provided doesn't have any answer.But my question is not though different it was asked in my question to verify my answer where the OP in your link doesn't do this rather he asked the question for searching answer.So why do you claim my question is the exactly duplicate of that one?

Comment: I just said by that that you use the same textbook with the same answers. Could you tell the name of this book ?

Comment: It is a question of Indian Statistical Institute undergraduate entrance exam BMATH 2016.

Comment: @ArnabChatterjee Ah I was messing some proportions, my apologies.  Actually this problem has a simple answer.  A centered circle has at least 5 normals directed to or away from the origin.  Since putting $a = c, b = 0, d = 0$ into the ellipse equation gives a circle, and (a) (b) and (c) don't satisfy that, then the answer has to be (d).  Simple logic, no algebra needed.  Unless your question is "exactly 5" instead of "at least 5".